# python sqlite SELECT combine AND with OR

Tags: python, sql, select

I would like to know how can I combine "AND with OR" in SELECT sql statement.
(using python 3.6 and sqlite 3.25.1)
heres the table
[image]

example I would like to select items with food in their 'title' or 'topic' 
that are created by '1'

here's my current code:

```
    def find_note(self, value, user_id):

        self.cur.execute("""SELECT id, title, topic, content, created_at, 
        modified_at FROM noteTbl
        WHERE title = ? OR topic = ? AND created_by = ?""",(value, value, 
                                                            user_id))
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        return result
```

and then after that I printed it:`

```
x = NoteDb()
for row in x.find_note('food',1):
print(row)
```

and I get blank.

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parenthesis to set the correct evaluation priority. In your case the `OR` needs to be evaluated first, then the `AND`:

```
SELECT id, title, topic, content, created_at, modified_at
FROM noteTbl
WHERE (title = ? OR topic = ?) AND created_by = ?
```